# Why is my pagination not working? (Django)

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x

I've been working with Django-Listviews and I used `paginate_py` in a class to get some pagination going. But it'll just show all the items. This is the class:

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = publicaciones
    template_name = 'store/search.html'
    context_object_name = 'queryset'
    ordering = ['Promocionado']
    paginate_by = 2

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = self.model.objects.all().order_by('id')
        search = self.request.GET.get('q')

        if search:
            qs = qs.filter(Título__icontains=search)

        return qs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        MyFilter = PubFilters(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
        context['filter'] = MyFilter
        context['filtered_items'] = MyFilter.qs
        context['count'] = self.get_queryset().count()
        context['búsqueda'] = self.request.GET.get('q')
        return context
```

Please tell me if I need to post anything else, like ***filters.py*** and so on. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: New traceback:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this block from sources https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/list.py#L113

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes sense, since the pagination is done on the result of `get_queryset` with the [**`.paginate_queryset(..)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.paginate_queryset) which returns a 4-tuple: `(paginator, page, object_list, is_paginated)`.

```
from django.http import QueryDict

class PostListView(ListView):

    # …

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        MyFilter = PubFilters(self.request.GET, queryset=queryset)
        paginator, page, object_list, is_paginated = self.paginate_queryset(
            queryset,
            self.get_paginated_by(queryset)
        )
        queries = self.request.GET.copy()
        queries.pop('page', None)
        context.update(
            filter=MyFilter,
            filtered_items=object_list,
            page=page,
            is_paginated=is_paginated,
            count=paginator.count,
            queries=queries
        )
        context['búsqueda'] = self.request.GET.get('q')
        return context
```

Note that in the links to other pages, if you want to retain the filtering, you will need to add the querystring part of the request parameters, so something like:

```
<a href="?page=2&{{ queries.urlencode|safe }}">
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. self.get_paginated_by() doesn't exist, i think it's self.get_paginate_by() and it takes one argument, in wich I wrote 'queryset', but I'm getting the error 'expected string or bytes-like object'

Comment: @MartínSchere: can you edit the question with the full traceback?

Comment: @MartínSchere: ah yes, if the `QueryDict` contains elements, then you can not pass it to the constructor. Updated with a fix.

Comment: Thank you sir! I see why you have such a good reputation. Really appreciate that